# Incorrect Display of Characters in the MainMenu at run time

Tags: delphi

At design time items of MainMenu looks correctly but at run time, after I add this code in FormCreate procedure of main form, I get incorrect, overlapped characters of mainmenu :

```
MainMenu1.OwnerDraw:= True;
 Screen.MenuFont.Name:= 'Tahoma';                                   
 Screen.MenuFont.Size:=12;
```

Font of main form is "Tahoma', size 12. Without this code characters of mainmenu are small and therefore I use this code.
If I exclude this code then characters are displayed well but are small.
To find out the reason I create new manimenu component but the same result.

I use Windows 10, windows 11;
Delphi 10.4.2

Thank you

update: I create new project. If I use this code at run time I get correct but small characters in mainmenu but if I set Mainmenu1.OwnerDraw to True in Object Inspector then I get the same problem: big but overlapped characters.

[image: screen]

Comment: Why not use the default system font (the one the user has chosen)?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I didn't understand exactly what do you mean . Font  of main form is "tahoma', size 12.  Without this code characters of mainmenu are small and therefore I use this code.  But sometimes I get error: list index out of bounds.  I don't know why I get this error and if it is related with this code.  If I exclude this code then characters are displayed well but are small.

Comment: But if you don't include these three lines of code, then your  menu will look exactly like every other Win32 menu on your desktop, won't it? And so, if you think this is too small to be comfortably read, then you must think the same of every other Win32 menu on your desktop? And thus the solution is to increase the system-wide font size. These days, this means increasing the DPI of your desktop.

Comment: Or the scaling factor... @basti this sounds like a HighDPI (4k screen) problem?

Comment: I believe Delphi Coder is on right track. This does appear to be issue with HighDPI awareness of your application. I recommend you check your [Project Options -> Application -> Manifest File](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Application_Options#Manifest_File_.28Windows_Only.29)  so that your application has proper DPI Awareness selected.

Comment: @SilverWarior Delphi Coder  Andreas Rejband   I tried all DPI Awareness options (none, Unaware, System Aware, Per monitor, Per monitor2, GDI scaling)  but without success. The only way I find is adding blanks before and after menuitem caption in order to not overlap characters of neighboring items.

Comment: @basti: Is the menu font in your VCL app smaller than in any other Win32 app?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand No. The same in other applications

Comment: Yes, that's my point! So (1) if you think the font is too small in your app and (2) the font has the same size in all other apps, then (3) the font is too small in every app. The solution, then, is NOT to adjust the font manually in your app so it suits your desktop, but to adjust your Windows desktop's DPI scaling. If you do that, then ALL your apps on your machine will look good. On the other hand, if you manually adjust the size in your app to suit your desktop, then your app will no longer suit all your other users, since they have different DPI preferences.

Comment: Just press the Win key, type "dpi" and select the appropriate settings item (maybe called something like "Change size of text, apps, and other objects").

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand adjusting desktop's DPI scaling didn't change anything, maybe because graphic adapter is old. After that I add blanks in menuitems captions, before and after characters and it works. I tried on the other comps and it looks well. I will test later. Thank you for you attempt to help.

Comment: If the font without that code matches all other menus on the system, leave it alone - that's how the user has set up the system, and it matches everything else on the system. You should NOT interfere with the user's ability to configure their OS and applications by forcing your tastes on them. Leave their systems alone, and write your apps to respect the user's choices. If an app insists on forcing its preferences over mine, that app would be removed, and I'd be leaving horrible reviews everywhere I could to let people know how badly it was designed.

Comment: @basti define "old graphic adapter", but that's certainly not the reason! Scaling was available since at least Win XP I think, maybe even longer ago! I also don't believe that this didn't change anything. But you failed again to provide any details what you did.

Comment: For me it works fine under Delphi 11.3, BUT only if:
- the menu font and size are set in the .dpr file before creating the form.
- the main menu OwnerDraw property is set to true in the inspector.

Comment: @Delphi Coder, 'what you did': I change  scale from 100% to 125% but  characters have become bigger but ugly, bold and blurry, and Characters remained overlapped as before.

Comment: @DelphiCoder I use SeaGurl's code from this link https://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=150771. But with this code characters became bigger  but remained overlapped.  Only in case if I insert blanks after and before characters of menuitems captions characters become even readable, not overlapped.

Comment: @dwrbudr what you write in .dpr file? May you explain clearly, with example? And why before creating the form.

Comment: @basti Answering on behalf of dwrbudr:   Application.Initialize;  Screen.MenuFont.Name:= 'Segoe UI';  Screen.MenuFont.Size:=15;  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;. Before creating the form, because then it works. Remember to set MainMenu1.Ownerdraw := True, e.g. in Object Inspector.

Comment: @TomBrunberg great. It works fine. Very simple way and nice menu. Thank you very much.